# I am getting error while building the project. Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.3.0' not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

The pom.xml is as shown below

Here the `codehaus.mojo` is not proper and is highlighted as red and mouse hover says

`Plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.3.0' not found.`

Post building the project we get this error

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project abc**.t found.`

```
<build>
            <defaultGoal>exec:exec</defaultGoal>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.3.0</version>
                    <!--    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId> -->
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-cli</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>${script.executor}</executable>
                                <commandlineArgs>${script.to.execute}</commandlineArgs>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Comment: I think this is a IDE problem. 
If you are using Eclipse/STS you might need to install some M2E Connector for the IDE being able to execute some specific maven goals.
Are you getting the same error when invoking the build from command line?

Comment: @cisk thanks for replying
I have tried running the command both in IntelliJ and in command line. Getting errors.

Comment: Can you please post the output when you run in the command line?: 
mvn clean install

Comment: add debug option and force update:
mvn clean install -U -X